# CakePHP: find neighbors is giving wrong array

Tags: php, cakephp-2.0

My Code is:

```
$this->Product->id = $product_range_detail['Product']['id'];
    $product_neighbors_details = $this->Product->find('neighbors',array(
        'conditions'=>array('Product.is_active'=>1,'Product.is_deleted'=>0,'Product.parent_id'=>0),
        'order'=>'Product.display_order ASC',
        'fields'=>array('id','name','slug','display_order'),
        'value'=>$product_range_detail['Product']['id']
    ));
```

Array comes like this :

```
Array (
    [prev] =>
    [next] => Array (
        [Product] => Array (
            [id] => 130
            [name] => Polyurethane Foam
            [slug] => polyurethane-foam
            [display_order] => 1
        )
    )
)
```

But I need next as prev and prev as next.
I tried to change the order but its not working.

SQL queries are also coming like this:

```
SELECT `Product`.`id`, `Product`.`name`, `Product`.`slug`,
`Product`.`display_order` FROM `mil_db`.`products` AS `Product`
WHERE `Product`.`is_active` = 1 AND `Product`.`is_deleted` = '0'
AND `Product`.`parent_id` = 0 AND `Product`.`id` < 124
ORDER BY `Product`.`id` DESC LIMIT 1
```

```
SELECT `Product`.`id`, `Product`.`name`, `Product`.`slug`,
`Product`.`display_order` FROM `mil_db`.`products` AS `Product`
WHERE `Product`.`is_active` = 1 AND `Product`.`is_deleted` = '0'
AND `Product`.`parent_id` = 0 AND `Product`.`id` > 124
ORDER BY `Product`.`id` ASC LIMIT 1
```

Comment: The current id is 124 so the next one is 130. why do you want the greater id to be in the Prev?

Comment: I need neighbors on based on product display order not product id ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally after 5 hour I got the solution:

```
$this->Product->id = $product_range_detail['Product']['id'];
    $product_neighbors_details = array();
    $product_neighbors_details = $this->Product->find('neighbors',array(
        'conditions'=>array('Product.is_active'=>1,'Product.is_deleted'=>0,'Product.parent_id'=>$product_range_detail['Product']['parent_id']),
        'order'=>array('Product.display_order'),
        'fields'=>array('id','name','slug', 'display_order'),
        'field' => 'display_order', 'value' => $product_range_detail['Product']['display_order']
    ));
```

Actually if I don't set field value then cake php by default taking primary key as a field.